# C++ Need Help with Displaying Results in Main() DEBUGGING

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, variable-assignment

Hey everyone here is my code

ive tried to display my results with no luck

i get an error

```
count was not declared in this scope

    int main()
    {
        CircularList<int> channelList(0);
        cout << "Value Stored: " << channelList.GetValue() << endl;  <--- OVER HERE
}
```

**Can some please help me display my results, or provide a solution 
much grateful**

here is the rest of my program

```
/*
 *  CircularList.h
 *       *
 *  Created by  on 30/08/11.
 *  Copyright 2011 ____. All rights reserved.
 *
 */

#ifndef _CIRCULARLIST_CPP_
#define _CIRCULARLIST_CPP_
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cctype>
#include "CircularList.h"


template<class T> CircularList<T>::CircularList(T emptyValue) {
    m_EmptyValue = emptyValue;
    m_CurrentNode = NULL;
}

template<class T> void CircularList<T>::InsertBefore(T data) {
    if(m_CurrentNode == NULL) {
        m_CurrentNode = new ListNode<T>();
        m_CurrentNode->value = data;
        m_CurrentNode->next = m_CurrentNode;
        m_CurrentNode->previous = m_CurrentNode;
        return;
    }

    ListNode<T>* tempNode = new ListNode<T>();
    tempNode->next = m_CurrentNode;
    tempNode->previous = m_CurrentNode->previous;
    m_CurrentNode->previous->next = tempNode;
    tempNode->value = data;
    m_CurrentNode->previous = tempNode;
    m_CurrentNode = tempNode;
}

template<class T> void CircularList<T>::InsertAfter(T data) {
    if(m_CurrentNode == NULL) {
        m_CurrentNode = new ListNode<T>();
        m_CurrentNode->value = data;
        m_CurrentNode->next = m_CurrentNode;
        m_CurrentNode->previous = m_CurrentNode;
        return;
    }

    ListNode<T>* tempNode = new ListNode<T>();
    tempNode->previous = m_CurrentNode;
    tempNode->next = m_CurrentNode->next;
    m_CurrentNode->next->previous = tempNode;
    tempNode->value = data;
    m_CurrentNode->next = tempNode;
    m_CurrentNode = tempNode;
}

template<class T> T CircularList<T>::GetValue() {
    if(m_CurrentNode == NULL) return m_EmptyValue;
    return m_CurrentNode->value;
}

template<class T> T CircularList<T>::NextValue() {
    if(m_CurrentNode == NULL) return m_EmptyValue;
    m_CurrentNode = m_CurrentNode->next;
    return m_CurrentNode->value;
}

template<class T> T CircularList<T>::PreviousValue() {
    if(m_CurrentNode == NULL) return m_EmptyValue;
    m_CurrentNode = m_CurrentNode->previous;
    return m_CurrentNode->value;
}

template<class T> CircularList<T>::~CircularList() {
    while(m_CurrentNode->next != m_CurrentNode && m_CurrentNode->previous != m_CurrentNode) {
        ListNode<T>* prevNode = m_CurrentNode->previous;
        ListNode<T>* nextNode = m_CurrentNode->next;

        prevNode->next = nextNode;
        nextNode->previous = prevNode;

        delete m_CurrentNode;
        m_CurrentNode = nextNode;
    }

    delete m_CurrentNode;
    m_CurrentNode = NULL;
}

    int main()
    {
        CircularList<int> channelList(0);
        cout << "Value Stored: " << channelList.GetValue() << endl;
}

#endif
```

Comment: Not sure what you were trying to accomplish with [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7241354/4) but please don't do that. If you want to delete your question, go ahead and delete it, or flag it to a mod if you can't do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect one of the following:

- you have mistyped `cout` as `count` in your actual code.
- you have mistyped `cout` as `count` in the error message that you provided above, and you haven't got a `using namespace std;` or `using std::cout;` in your actual code.  (Alternatively, you can just fully qualify `cout`, as `std::cout`.)

[Note: never do `using namespace XXX;` in a header file.]

Comment: Or he mistyped the error and the problem is that std::cout is what is really needed.

Comment: so i tried  std::count << "Value Stored: " << channelList.GetValue() << endl; and it doesnt work... how can i display my get value

Answer (score 0):

you must qualify the scope of `std::cout`, like so:

```
    std::cout << "Value Stored: " << channelList.GetValue() << std::endl;
```

Comment: In that case, he would also need `std::endl`.

Comment: thanks guys 
now im getting an error

while(m_CurrentNode->next != m_CurrentNode && m_CurrentNode->previous != m_CurrentNode) 

saying EXC_BAD_ACCESS ???